# Socket.io - unexpected data received

Tags: javascript, socket.io, flask-socketio

So, I was searching far and wide but haven't been able to find an answer. I'm currently developing an application with typescript(v2.8.3) and react.js(v16.4.0), which connects to the flask server using socket.io client(v2.1.0).  Once every run, I'm receiving data which looks like the data that was actually sent from the server 
 but replicated multiple times. I have created handler for specific message, which looks like this:

```
 this.props.socket.on("some_message", this.handleSomeMessage);
 private handleSomeMessage = (message: any) => {
        console.log(message);
        this.setState({data: message.diff});
};
```

I have logged request that are being sent from server on server side:

```
        if self.key_to_event_dict[key] == "some_message":
        with open("sent.txt", "a") as f:
            json.dump(diff_obj, f)

    self.socketio.emit(
        self.key_to_event_dict[key],
        diff_obj
    )
```

Here is the diff logged from the server side:

```
[{
"diff": {
  "main": {
    "values": [[0],[11.66],[9.82],[10.707500000000001], [0.8743962202571556]],
    "labels": ["gen", "max", "min", "avg", "std"]
  },
  "fp": {
    "values": [[], [], [], [], []],
    "labels": ["gen", "max", "min", "avg", "std"]
  }
}
},{
"diff": {
  "main": {
    "values": [[], [], [], [], []],
    "labels": ["gen", "max", "min", "avg", "std"]
  },
  "fp": {
    "values": [[], [1.539999999999999], [0.570000000000000], 
 [0.832500000000000], [0.40880160224734857]],
    "labels": ["gen", "max", "min", "avg", "std"]
}
    }
},
{
"diff": {
  "main": {
    "values": [[1], [15.32], [8.92], [10.8175], [2.61861007979424]],
    "labels": ["gen", "max", "min", "avg", "std"]
  },
  "fp": {
    "values": [[], [], [], [], []
    ],
    "labels": ["gen", "max", "min", "avg", "std"]
  }
}
},
{
"diff": {
  "main": {
    "values": [[2], [15.32], [9.23], [11.037500000000001], 
[2.4834288292600615]],
    "labels": ["gen", "max", "min", "avg", "std"]
  },
  "fp": {
    "values": [[1, 2], [1.5399999999999991, 0.6100000000000012], 
[0.5700000000000003, 0.5700000000000003], [0.8325000000000005, 
0.600000000000001], [0.40880160224734857, 0.017320508075689172]],
    "labels": ["gen", "max", "min", "avg", "std"]
  }
}
},
{
"diff": {
  "main": {
    "values": [[3], [16.75], [9.23], [14.155000000000001], 
[2.9027616161166248]],
    "labels": ["gen", "max", "min", "avg", "std" ]
  },
  "fp": {
    "values": [[], [], [], [], []],
    "labels": ["gen", "max", "min", "avg", "std" ]
  }
}
},
{
"diff": {
  "main": {
    "values": [[], [], [], [], [],[]],
    "labels": ["gen", "max", "min", "avg", "std"]
  },
  "fp": {
    "values": [[3], [0.6100000000000012], [0.5700000000000003], [0.5900000000000007], [0.020000000000000462]
    ],
    "labels": ["gen", "max", "min", "avg", "std"]
  }
}
}
]
```

As you can see there is at most 2 values returned in each message. However, when this message is being read inside the client:

[Socket.io log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnRQx.png)

My handler is logging message that has almost 30 values in each array, and they are looking like multiplication of values received previously. Here you can see the picture :

[logged object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMwJC.png)

As you can see the main section contains the same values as previously, but replicated 20-30 times. Can it be some issue with messages not being confirmed after receiving a response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question:
The problem was caused by registering too much event handlers in one place. I was having a component that was maintaining 5 event handlers at the time, and after dividing into 3 separate components I finally got rid of unexpected data. Still don't know the origin of the error though, will try to investigate that and create issue in socket.io github page.